# $d(n)$ is odd if and only if $n = k^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can someone help me prove that $d(n)$ is odd if and only if $n = k^2$ for some integer $k$?

For reference:
$d(n)$ gives the number of positive divisors of $n$, including $n$ itself.

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange

Comment: **Hint** $\ $ Show that the  cofactor map $\ a\mapsto n/a\,$ *pairs* each factor of $n$ with its cofactor, giving an even number of factors, except if there is some $\, a = n/a,\,$ i.e. when $\, n = a^2$ is a perfect square.
$\tag*{}$
**Remark** $\ $ This is a prototypical example of exploitation of involution (reflection) symmetry. [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+involution+) for more examples. $\tag*{}$

Comment: This might help: http://oeis.org/wiki/Index_entries_for_number_of_divisors Remember: if $n = k^{2m}$, then $n = (k^m)^2$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Try to pair every divisor $d$ with $n/d$, which is the only element which would not have a pair?

Comment: I have trouble understanding what your hint is saying

Comment: For each divisor $d$ take $d$ and $n/d$ and put them in a pair of two. If you do this all of the divisors will be in groups of $2$, so the number of divisors will be even.

Comment: So how does this prove that d(n) is odd?

Comment: Which is the only divisor $d$ which could possibly not have a pair?

Comment: Is it possibly 1?

Comment: The pair of $1$ would be $n/1=n$ , $1$ does have a pair.

Comment: So then what would it be?

Comment: Would it perhaps be n?

Comment: The pair of $n$ is $1$. Henno Brandsma's answer uses the solution to my hint. The element that wouldn't have a pair would be $\sqrt n$ because it is it's own pair, of course that element is only a divisor if $n$ is a square.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : A number with the prime factorization $p_1^{a_1}\times ...\times p_n^{a_n}$ has
        $(a_1+1)\times ...\times (a_n+1)$ divisors. When is the latter product odd ?

Comment: When each of the terms are odd?

Comment: Exactly that, and then the exponents are all even, so we have a perfect square.

Comment: So how would I exactly compile a proof on this. So meaning how would I exaplain this.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $D$, the set of all divisors of $n$.

Define a map $f: D \rightarrow D$ by $f(d) = \frac{n}{d}$, which is well defined (as $d$ is a divisor of $n$) and self inverse because $f(f(d)) = f(\frac{n}{d}) = \frac{n}{\frac{n}{d}} = d$.

When $x < \sqrt{n}$ (as reals), then $f(x) > \sqrt{n}$ and vice versa, so $f(x) \neq x$ for all those $x$. So if $\sqrt{n}$ is not an integer, there is no fixed point for $f$ and $D$ is exactly divided in $D_1 = \{d \in D: d < \sqrt{n}\}$ and $D_2 = \{d \in D: d > \sqrt{n}\}$ and these have equal size, as $f$ is a bijection between them. So $|D|$ is even.

So $n$ no square implies $d(n)$ is even. If $n$ is a square $D = D_1 \cup D_2 \cup \{\sqrt{n}\}$. Again, $f$ shows that $|D_1| = |D_2|$ and $d(n)$ is odd.

Comment: I am not familiar with "define a map" can you exaplain it to me?

Comment: A map is another word for function.